# Counting how many times you borrow

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I have a problem with this code, wherein you have to count how many times you borrow in order to do subtraction.
For example:

```
x = 312;
y = 34;
```

The output should be: 2 because you have borrowed 2 times in subtraction.
My problem is like this, whenever I input x=12, y=2, the output is 1, also, when x = 12, y = 1. It should be 0.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BorrowOut{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x;
        int y;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int minus = 0, borrow = 0;
        int c1 = 0, c2 = 0;

        System.out.print("\nx: ");
        x = in.nextInt();

        //this will convert the integer (x) into string and then count its length;
        int len = (Integer.toString(x).length());
        int[] a = new int[len];

        System.out.print("y: ");
        y = in.nextInt();

        minus = x - y;
        System.out.print("\nDifference: " + minus);

        //this will convert the integer (y) into string and then count its length
        int len2 = (Integer.toString(y).length());
        int[] b = new int[len2];

        //splitting the inputs into a single token storing it in an array
        while(x>0 && y>0)
        {
            a[i++] = x % 10;
            x = x/10;
        }
        while(y>0)
        {
            b[j++] = y % 10;
            y = y/10;
        }
        /*System.out.println("\nx");

        //printing out the index and the token
        for (int k = 0; k<a.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.println("a[" + k + "] " + a[k]);
        }
        System.out.println("\ny");
        for (int l = 0; l<b.length; l++)
        {
            System.out.println("b[" + l + "] " + b[l]);
        }*/
        for (int k = 0; k<a.length; k++)
            for (int l = 0; l<b.length; l++)
        {
            c1 = k;
            c2 = l;
            if (a[k]<b[l])
            {
                a[k] = a[k] + 10;
                borrow+=1;
            }

        }
        if (c1!=c2)
        {
                borrow-=1;
        }
        System.out.print ("\nBorrow: " + borrow);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem your code is supposed to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you've written a double loop.

```
for (int k = 0; k<a.length; k++)
    for (int l = 0; l<b.length; l++)
{
    c1 = k;
    c2 = l;
    if (a[k]<b[l])
    {
        a[k] = a[k] + 10;
        borrow+=1;
    }

}
```

What this does is: It sets `k` to 0, then while `k` is 0, you use `l` as an index to go over the entire array `b`.  Then it increases `k` to 1, then starts `l` over at the beginning to go over the entire array `b`.  Then `k` becomes 2, and it goes over the array `b` yet again ... This isn't what you want.  It's the sort of thing you might do if you were multiplying the numbers.  But when you're subtracting them, you want to go through the arrays in *parallel*--that is, look at `a[0]` and `b[0]` at the same time, `a[1]` and `b[1]`, `a[2]` and `b[2]` etc.  To do that, you want to use only a single loop, and one index.  (And you will need to be careful about how you handle it if one array is shorter than the other.)  (Make sure you test your program on 10000 minus 9999.)

(P.S. It's best to avoid the single letter `l` as a variable name.  It looks too much like a `1`.)

**More:** To answer a question that I think you were asking in a comment: For this problem, your index will be the same for both `a` and `b`, since you've stored the digits backwards, with the low-order digit in `a[0]` and `b[0]` (a good approach for this problem).  If you have a similar problem where you need to go through two arrays in parallel but with different indexes, you can put multiple indexes in a single `for` statement.  Say you have two arrays that could be of different lengths, and you want to go backward through both arrays and stop whenever the beginning of the shorter one is reached:

```
for (int i = array1.length - 1, j = array2.length - 1;
     i >= 0 && j >= 0;
     i--, j--) {
    // do something with array1[i] and array2[j]
}
```

Each time through the loop, it decrements both `i` and `j`.  This is very different from a double loop with one `for` nested inside another; in the double loop, only the inner index is changed while the outer index remains the same; then when the inner loop is done with the inner index, **then** the outer index is changed and the inner loop is started over.

Comment: The result was just fine with 10000 - 9999 with 4 borrows.

Hmm how should I handle it when they have different index in one loop??

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest edited code. My problem now is like this:

x = 4500; y = 599;

the output is 2, it should be 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BorrowOut{
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int minus = 0, borrow = 0;
    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0;

    System.out.print("\nx: ");
    x = in.nextInt();

    //this will convert the integer (x) into string and then count its length;
    int len = (Integer.toString(x).length());
    int[] a = new int[len];

    System.out.print("y: ");
    y = in.nextInt();

    minus = x - y;
    System.out.print("\nDifference: " + minus);

    //this will convert the integer (y) into string and then count its length
    int len2 = (Integer.toString(y).length());
    int[] b = new int[len2];

    //splitting the inputs into a single token storing it in an array
    while(x>0 && y>0)
    {
        a[i++] = x % 10;
        x = x/10;
    }
    while(y>0)
    {
        b[j++] = y % 10;
        y = y/10;
    }


    for (int k = 0; k<a.length; k++)
        for (int m = 0; m<b.length; m++)
    {
        c1 = k;
        c2 = m;
    }

    int aa=0;
    if (c1>c2)
    {
        aa = c1;
    }
    else
    {
        aa = c2;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k<aa; k++)
    {
        if (a[k]<b[k])
        {
            a[k] = a[k] + 10;
            borrow+=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print ("\nBorrow: " + borrow);
    System.out.println();
}
```

}